# AngularJS select image from list

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome, angularjs-ng-click

I'm implementing simple pictures list.
here's my code. I have 2 questions:
1. I want to make a single choice whenever the user click an image. Whenever he choose one picture it will clear the other choice. how can I do that?
2. Instead of border I would like to use an icon such as fa-check (http://fontawesome.io/icon/check/). How can I combine it in the css?

Thanks!

### css file

```
.selected {
   border:2px solid red;
}
```

### js file

```
$scope.items = [
    {imageUrl: '/app/img/item1.jpg'},
    {imageUrl: '/app/img/item2.jpg'}];

$scope.toggle = function (item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
  };
```

### html file

```
<div class="category rating-type">
<h5>items list</h5>
<div class="pics-continer">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="toggle(item)" ng-class="{'selected':item.selected}">
            <div style="background-image: url({{item.imageUrl}});height:36px; width:40px;display:inline-block"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using a selected flag in each item, use a `selectedItem` field in the scope, and set it to the clicked item.

Comment: Thanks JB ! I'm newbie in AngularJS. Do you have a good example or reference where I can follow your sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your taggle method as follows to have a single select image list.

```
    $scope.toggle = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedImage = item.imageUrl;
    };
```

And change the view as

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="toggle(item)" ng-class="{'selected':item.imageUrl == selectedImage}">
        <img src="{{item.imageUrl}}" style="height:36px; width:40px;"/>
    </li>
```

So only one image can be selected at the same time.

For using an icon instead of border you can set the icon as background image.
the following link are usefull

[CSS background-position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it is best put as much code as possible in the controller - this is easier to test. So: the html snippet:

   ```
   <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectItem(item)" 

       ng-class="{'fa fa-check':isSelected(item)}">

        <div style="background-image: url({{item.imageUrl}});
        height:36px; width:40px;display:inline-block"></div>
   </li>
   ```

the controller:

```
controller('TestController', function($scope){
   $scope.items = [
    {imageUrl: '/app/img/item1.jpg'},
    {imageUrl: '/app/img/item2.jpg'}
   ];
   $scope.selectedItem = null;

   $scope.selectItem = function(item){
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
   };

   $scope.isSelected = function(item){
    if($scope.selectedItem===null){
        return false;
    }
    return item.imageUrl === $scope.selectedItem.imageUrl;
   };
})
```

1. how to setup fontawesome is documented here: http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ After that you can use the css class names provided by fontawesome. Also included in the example above.

Comment: @DaveMartin: then you should accept it by clicking the gray check at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.items = [
    {imageUrl: '/app/img/item1.jpg'},
    {imageUrl: '/app/img/item2.jpg'}];

$scope.toggle = function (item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
  };
```

that `item` is a `index` for `items`, but you didn't set `selected` in your `items` array . So `item.selected` it's threw undefined error

Please try this way

```
$scope.items = [
        {imageUrl: '/app/img/item1.jpg',selected:true},
        {imageUrl: '/app/img/item2.jpg',selected:false}];
```